# Paypal form submitting USD instead of GBP

Tags: php, forms, paypal

On my website, when you fill out the donation form at the bottom of the page and click 'Make Donation', you are directed to PayPal and greeted with the following error message:

> This recipient does not accept payments denominated in USD. Please contact the seller and ask him to update his payment receiving preferences to accept this currency.

So it seems my website is trying to submit the donation amount in USD and it should be submitting it in GBP... From the code I have, I can't see anything that relates to USD, I see this in code for the donate form:

```
<div id="donate_form" style="width:465px; text-align:right; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">      
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" target="_self" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">

<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="office@lifechurch.org.uk">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="GB">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="CLC">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.lifechurchgive.org.uk/thanks.php">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.lifechurchgive.org.uk/cancel.php">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<!--<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7-----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-----END PKCS7-----">-->
<span id="ajaxresult" name="ajaxresult"><?PHP include("validate.php"); ?></span>

<?PHP 
#$ajax = "loadXMLDoc('/validate.php','ajaxresult','submit2','displaydonation=true&amp;title1='+title1.value+'&amp;first_name='+first_name.value+'&amp;last_name='+last_name.value+'&amp;H_PhoneNumber='+H_PhoneNumber.value+'&amp;email='+email.value+'&amp;amount='+amount.value+'&amp;message='+message.value);document.getElementById('submit2').disabled=true;cursor_wait();";

$ajax = "loadXMLDoc('/validate.php','ajaxresult','submit2','displaydonation=true&amp;title1='+title1.value+'&amp;first_name='+first_name.value+'&amp;last_name='+last_name.value+'&amp;email='+email.value+'&amp;amount='+amount.value+'&amp;message='+message.value+'&amp;giftaid='+giftaid.checked);document.getElementById('submit2').disabled=true;cursor_wait();";

echo '<br /><div class="submitbutton">'.make_form_var('input','button','submit2','submit2','Make Donation','','','','','','','','','',$ajax).'</div>';
?>
</form>

<!--
<a href="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=6210814"><img src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" /></a> -->

</div><!-- end of donate_form -->
```

It does have a lot thats commented out.

I have a validate.php file, but I don't see anything about currency / GBP / USD in there so there must be something that sets it to USD but doesn't use those terms perhaps?

I'll actually post the code thats in the validation.php file sorry about the length...

```
<?PHP

ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

#session_start();

function make_form_var($formvar='',$type='',$name='',$id='',$value='',$size='',$maxlength='',$checked='',$src='',$rows='',$columns='',$class='',$title='',$align='',$onclick='',$onblur='') {

        if ($formvar == '') { return; }

        $object = '<'.$formvar.' ';                                                     # 1
        if ($type != '')        { $object.= 'type="'.$type.'" '; }                      # 2
        if ($name != '')        { $object.= 'name="'.$name.'" '; }                      # 3
        if ($id != '')          { $object.= 'id="'.$id.'" '; }                          # 4
        if ($value != '')       { $object.= 'value="'.$value.'" '; }                    # 5
        if ($size != '')        { $object.= 'size="'.$size.'" '; }                      # 6
        if ($maxlength != '')   { $object.= 'maxlength="'.$maxlength.'" '; }            # 7
        if ($checked != '')     { $object.= 'checked="'.$checked.'" '; }                # 8
        if ($src != '')         { $object.= 'src="'.$src.'" '; }                        # 9
        if ($rows != '')        { $object.= 'rows="'.$rows.'" '; }                      # 10
        if ($columns != '')     { $object.= 'cols="'.$columns.'" '; }                   # 11
        if ($class != '')       { $object.= 'class="'.$class.'" '; }                    # 12
        if ($title != '')       { $object.= 'title="'.$title.'" '; }                    # 13
        if ($align != '')       { $object.= 'align="'.$align.'" '; }                    # 14
        if ($onclick != '')     { $object.= 'onclick="'.$onclick.'" '; }                # 15
        if ($onblur != '')      { $object.= 'onblur="'.$onblur.'" '; }                  # 16

        if ($formvar == 'textarea') {
                $object.='>'.$value.'</'.$formvar.'>';
        } else {
                $object.=' />';
        }

        return $object;
}

function valid_email($email)
{
// check an email address is valid
if (preg_match('/^([0-9a-zA-Z]+[-._+&])*[0-9a-zA-Z]+@([-0-9a-zA-Z]+[.])+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/', $email))

return true;
else
return false;
}

$newarray = $_POST;

if ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/index.php' || isset($_POST['displaydonation'])) {

    # place values on the session
    if (isset($newarray['title1'])) {
        $_SESSION['DONATION']->title1 = $newarray['title1'];
    } else {
        if (!isset($_SESSION['DONATION']->title1)) { $_SESSION['DONATION']->title1 = ''; }
    }

    if (isset($newarray['first_name'])) {
        $_SESSION['DONATION']->first_name = $newarray['first_name'];
    } else {
        if (!isset($_SESSION['DONATION']->first_name)) { $_SESSION['DONATION']->first_name = ''; }
    }

    if (isset($newarray['last_name'])) {
        $_SESSION['DONATION']->last_name = $newarray['last_name'];
    } else {
        if (!isset($_SESSION['DONATION']->last_name)) { $_SESSION['DONATION']->last_name = ''; }
    }

    if (isset($newarray['email'])) {
        $_SESSION['DONATION']->email = $newarray['email'];
    } else {
        if (!isset($_SESSION['DONATION']->email)) { $_SESSION['DONATION']->email = ''; }
    }

    if (isset($newarray['amount'])) {
        $_SESSION['DONATION']->amount = $newarray['amount'];
    } else {
        if (!isset($_SESSION['DONATION']->amount)) { $_SESSION['DONATION']->amount = '0.00'; }
    }

    if (isset($newarray['message'])) {
        $_SESSION['DONATION']->message = $newarray['message'];
    } else {
        if (!isset($_SESSION['DONATION']->message)) { $_SESSION['DONATION']->message = ''; }
    }

    if (isset($newarray['giftaid'])) {
        if ($newarray['giftaid'] == 'true') { $newarray['giftaid'] = 1; } else { $newarray['giftaid'] == 0; }
        $_SESSION['DONATION']->giftaid = $newarray['giftaid'];
    } else {
        if (!isset($_SESSION['DONATION']->giftaid)) { $_SESSION['DONATION']->giftaid = '1'; }
    }

    $emailvalid = ''; $emailvalid = valid_email($_SESSION['DONATION']->email);

    if (isset($_POST['displaydonation']) && $_SESSION['DONATION']->first_name != '' && $_SESSION['DONATION']->last_name != '' && $_SESSION['DONATION']->email != '' && $emailvalid != false && $_SESSION['DONATION']->amount != '' && $_SESSION['DONATION']->amount >= 5.00) {

        # email details
        $subject =  "Website Donation";
        $body = $body."The following donation was started on ".date('l dS F').". The user was forwarded to paypal to complete the transaction.\n\n";
        $body = $body."Contact Name: ".$_SESSION['DONATION']->title." ".$_SESSION['DONATION']->first_name." ".$_SESSION['DONATION']->last_name."\n\n";
        $body = $body."Email: ".$_SESSION['DONATION']->email."\n\n";
        $body = $body."Amount: ".$_SESSION['DONATION']->amount."\n\n";
        if ( $_SESSION['DONATION']->message != '')  { $body = $body."Message: ".$_SESSION['DONATION']->message."\n\n"; }
        if ( $_SESSION['DONATION']->giftaid == '1')     { $body = $body."Gift aid: Yes\n\n"; }

        $to =    "office@lifechurch.org.uk";
        $from = $_SESSION['DONATION']->email;
        $headers  = 'From: ' . $from . "\n";
        $headers .= 'Return-Path: ' . $from . "\n";
        $headers .= 'BCC: gavin.lloyd@sky.com'."\n";
        $headers .= 'BCC:'."\n";
        $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' ."\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1' ."\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit'. "\n\n";

        $mailOk=mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

        # forward form to paypal
        echo 'submitform';

    } else {

        echo '<div class="formlabel">Title: </div>';
        echo '<div class="formobject">';
        echo make_form_var('input','text','title1','title1',$_SESSION['DONATION']->title1,'5','6','','','','','paypaltextbox');
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="formclear"></div>';

        if (isset($_POST['displaydonation']) && $_SESSION['DONATION']->first_name == '') {
            echo '<div class="error">Please enter your first name:</div>';
        }

        echo '<div class="formlabel"><span class="requiredtext">First name:* </span></div>';
        echo '<div class="formobject">';
        echo make_form_var('input','text','first_name','first_name',$_SESSION['DONATION']->first_name,'26','100','','','','','paypaltextbox');
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="formclear"></div>';

        if (isset($_POST['displaydonation']) && $_SESSION['DONATION']->last_name == '') {
            echo '<div class="error">Please enter your last name:</div>';
        }

        echo '<div class="formlabel"><span class="requiredtext">Last name:* </span></div>';
        echo '<div class="formobject">';
        echo make_form_var('input','text','last_name','last_name',$_SESSION['DONATION']->last_name,'26','100','','','','','paypaltextbox');
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="formclear"></div>';



        if (isset($_POST['displaydonation']) && $_SESSION['DONATION']->email == '') {
            echo '<div class="error">Please enter your email:</div>';
        } else if (isset($_POST['displaydonation']) && $emailvalid == false) {
            echo '<div class="error">Please enter a valid email address:</div>';
        }

        echo '<div class="formlabel"><span class="requiredtext">Email:* </span></div>';
        echo '<div class="formobject">';
        echo make_form_var('input','text','email','email',$_SESSION['DONATION']->email,'26','100','','','','','paypaltextbox');
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="formclear"></div>';

        if (isset($_POST['displaydonation']) && $_SESSION['DONATION']->amount == '') {
            echo '<div class="error">Please enter a donation:</div>';
        } else if (isset($_POST['displaydonation']) && $_SESSION['DONATION']->amount < 5.00) {
            echo '<div class="error">Please enter a donation of &pound;5.00 or more:</div>';
        }

        echo '<div class="formlabel"><span class="requiredtext">Donation:* </span></div>';
        echo '<div class="formobject">';
        echo make_form_var('input','text','amount','amount',$_SESSION['DONATION']->amount,'6','16','','','','','paypaltextboxcost','','right','','MM_changeProp(\'amount\',\'\',\'value\',cent(this.value),\'INPUT/TEXT\')');
        echo ' (minimum &pound;5.00)</div>';
        echo '<div class="formclear"></div>';

        echo '<div class="formlabel">Message: </div>';
        echo '<div class="formobject">';
        echo make_form_var('textarea','','message','message',$_SESSION['DONATION']->message,'','','','','5','','paypaltextbox');
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="formclear"></div>';

        echo '<div class="formlabel">Gift aid: </div>';
        echo '<div class="formobject">';
        $checked='';
        if ($_SESSION['DONATION']->giftaid == 1) { $checked = 'checked'; }
        echo make_form_var('input','checkbox','giftaid','giftaid','1','','',$checked,'','','','');
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="formclear"><br /><p class="donate_small">I am a UK taxpayer. Please treat the gift I have made to Chesterfield Christian Life Church (CLC) as a Gift Aid Donation. I understand CLC will reclaim income tax at the basic rate on my donations and I must pay an amount of income tax or capital gains tax equal to the amount that will be reclaimed. IE - You are confirming that you are a UK tax payer and that you are happy for us to reclaim the tax - for every £1 you give to CLC we can reclaim 25p from the tax man - which is pretty cool. All donations qualify - large or small, regular or one-off, and whatever the method of payment. </p></div>';
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I should be looking for?

Comment: First, try changing 'currency_code' to just 'currency'. Then secondly, if that fails, try removing the underscore from your currency_code

Comment: Thanks ProEvilz - If I change those to either currency or currency code without the underscore, I don't get the same error message, but it does donate in USD instead of GBP still...